# How can i go bouts expanding or shrinking an array into another array?

Tags: java, arrays

how can I go about doing this?

```
public static double[] adjustFrequency(double[] samples, double factor) {
    // samples = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

    //adjustFrequency(samples, 0.5);
    //samples = (1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6}

    //adjustFrequency(sample, 0.5);
    //samples = {1,3,5}
}
```

Comment: Please describe exactly what you are trying to achieve, and include what you have already tried and why you think it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Java Array documentation, especially the function copyOfRange(). This will allow you to copy some parts of your array used for either shrinking or expanding.